# Can't read swagger JSON file on ASP.NET Core 1.2 Application after hosting into local IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-webapi

After hosting my asp.net core 1.2 application, I am getting an error as:

> swagger is unable to find the `swagger.json` file.

I have tried to solve the problem by giving a virtual path name `app.UseSwaggerUI()` but it's not working.

**Edit to clarify question based on comments:**

After hosting Asp.net core application in IIS, the `swagger.json` file is generating on `localhost:<random_port>/swagger/v1/swagger.json` path.

How do I serve the `swagger.json` file on a custom route like:
`localhost:<random_port>/virtualpathname/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

I have tried to set a virtual path in app.UseSwaggerUI() like `{virtualpathname}/swagger/v2/swagger.json` but still it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a few reasons for this - one being that .Net Core doesnt serve static files by default (although looking at online examples this doesnt seem to be an issue).

If you havent already, try installing the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` and adding `UseStaticFiles()` in your `Configure()` method in `Startup.cs` with the following configuration. I dont *think* that the order is important, but this is the order I have mine running in a working app.

```
public void Configure(...)
{
  // Enable middleware to serve static files (like .json)
  app.UseStaticFiles();

  //Enable middleware for your API
  app.UseMvc();

  // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
  app.UseSwagger();

  // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
  app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
  {
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "YourApp API V1");
  });
}
```

You will also need `SwaggerGen` middleware configured in your `ConfigureServices()` method.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "api_name", Version = "1.0"});
});
```

**Edit** Based on comment - to serve swagger json on a custom route:

```
// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint on a custom endpoint
app.UseSwagger(c => c.RouteTemplate = "custom/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json");

// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
// Using custom endpoint defined above
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/custom/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "YourApp API V1");
});
```

If you need to serve SwaggerUI on a custom route as well, then:

```
// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
// Using custom endpoint defined above
// And serving UI on a custom route
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/custom/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "YourApp API V1");
  c.RoutePrefix = "custom"; // serves UI on http://{domain}:{port}/custom/
});
```

Comment: hi i have already tried with above code still i am facing issue as per my understanding, swagger is generating its json file in _http://localhost:<random_port>/swagger/v1/swagger.json_ path but it should generate its json file in _http://localhost:<random_port>/virtualpathname/swagger/v1/swagger.json_ directory; i tried to give virtual path in  **app.UseSwaggerUI** like _{virtualpathname}/swagger/v2/swagger.json_ but still it is not working

Comment: yes i am able to resolve but one problem is that in swagger UI textbox manually i have to give json path

Comment: Sounds like your configuration between swagger itself and swaggerUI do not match. If you carefully compare the routes you are specifying you should be able to work out your problem - if not, please post a new question with example code demonstrating your issue. Finally, please remember to feed back to other users on this site, either by leaving comments, or upvoting/marking as answer when a question is resolved. [Read this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to perform the two next steps.

- First, open your project web.config and enable stdoutLogEnabled. (Remember to create the folder logs on your application folder and give it proper permissions)
- Second, make sure you're doing the right configuration. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger)

Note: The first step is going to give you more details about the error you're facing.

Comment: I thought you only used a _web.config_ file if hosting in IIS/IISExpress?

Comment: Not really, It is not like used to be, but still holds a few configurations.

Comment: After hosting Asp.net core application in IIS swagger.json file is generating in _http://localhost:<random_port>/swagger/v1/swagger.json_ path but it should be generate its json file in _http://localhost:<random_port>/virtualpathname/swagger/v1/swagger.json_ directory; i tried to give virtual path in  **app.UseSwaggerUI()** like _{virtualpathname}/swagger/v2/swagger.json_ but still it is not working

Comment: There is no config file in asp.net core 1.2 application

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was the virtual directory which I fixed by adding a relative path(../). In any case make sure you setup ConfigureServices first, then when Configure make sure everything is in order, UseSwagger should be before UseMvc and at the end UseSwaggerUI

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info { Title = "Utility", Version = "v1" });
        });
        // initialize configuration
        var conf = new ConfigurationHelper(Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.ApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath);
        Configuration = conf.Configuration; // just in case
        // inject the RestApiWrapperService as singleton into the services configuration
        var restService = new RestApiWrapperService(conf);
        services.AddSingleton<IRestApiWrapperService>(restService);
    }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseSwagger();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            // app.UseMvc();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSwaggerUI(s => {
                s.RoutePrefix = "help";
                s.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Utility");
                s.InjectStylesheet("../css/swagger.min.css");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following on your startup.cs class:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyService.API v1");

                });
```

To

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
              {
                  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/MyWebsiteName/swagger/v1/swagger.json", 
                    "MyService.API v1");

              });
```

[MyWebsiteName] being the name of application configured in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have a simple copy paste mistake!
see the first line in below code, the if statement env.IsDevelopment() is causing this section to not run when deployed to IIS. One option is to comment it out!

```
     //if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    app.UseSwagger(c =>
                    {
                        c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
                    });
                    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
                        c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
                        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "StockOps.WebAPI v1");                                   
                    });                
                }
```